# How to split an expression by space in bash?

Tags: bash, command-substitution, variable-substitution

I am getting the valid result I want in zsh but not bash, what am I missing? I am trying to split the string into words.

Bash

```
bash-3.2$ echo ${$(echo "Hello World")[@]}
bash: ${$(echo "Hello World")[@]}: bad substitution
```

zshrc

```
> echo ${$(echo "Hello World")[@]}
Hello World
```

Comment: Bash doesn't have nested substitution. Please provide a more realistic usecase.

Answer (score 3):

It's just that Bash doesn't do nested substitutions like that, but zsh does. This is similar:

```
$ zsh -c 'a=abcdef; echo ${${a%ef}#ab}'
cd
$ bash -c 'a=abcdef; echo ${${a%ef}#ab}'
bash: ${${a%ef}#ab}: bad substitution
```

The workaround is to use a temporary variable:

```
$ tmp=($(echo "Hello World"))
$ printf "%s\n" "${tmp[@]}"
Hello
World
```

Do note that;

- You usually want to add quotes around `"$@"` or `"${foo[@]}"`, as otherwise the expansion does word-splitting. That doesn't matter here, since it was already word-split at the assignment, but in general with arrays it does matter.
- The unquoted expansion in the assignment is also subject to filename globbing.
- `echo` isn't a very good tool to view the results of word splitting since it joins all the arguments with spaces, so you can't see if the spaces are there in the arguments, or if `echo` added them (`echo "foo bar" doo` has the same output as `echo foo bar doo`).